# Not able to fetch resource using getResources().getIdentifier

Tags: android

I need to fetch a drawable using its name so that I can set it in `imageView.setImageDrawable()`, which takes the int value;

The string I'm using say is, `img_state_btn`.

Code:

```
int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(icon, null,
                mContext.getPackageName());
imgView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(id));
```

I'm receiving correct package name, but value of id is coming out to be `0`.

Where I'm doing wrong?

P.S. - Do not want to use R.java

Comment: check you icon name it should match with..R.identifier name..then it returns correct value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get drawable id from name use following code. I think problem is you are passing null instead of "drawable"

```
int drawableResourceId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

Comment: I am using this method only resources.getIdentifier("female.png","drawable", mContext.getPackageName()) but still not able to find the resource. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try out as below :

You can get the id of an image with it's name by below code.

```
 int id= getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,"drawable", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+drawablename, "drawable",mContext.getPackageName());
```

(or)

```
int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(drawablename, "drawable",mContext.getPackageName());
```

JavaDoc for this

```
int android.content.res.Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)



public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage) 
Added in API level 1
Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here. 

Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Parameters
name  The name of the desired resource. 
defType  Optional default resource type to find, if "type/" is not included in the name. Can be null to require an explicit type. 
defPackage  Optional default package to find, if "package:" is not included in the name. Can be null to require an explicit package. 

Returns
int The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also directly set

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_state_btn);
```